# undefined symbol: ATL_chemv

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano

When I run this command

sudo python -c "import numpy; numpy.test()"

i get this error

ImportError: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv

How can I fix it?

Comment: You might check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8917977/1775603).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249089) will help resolve things better, especially if you want to keep all the options. Most others will tell you to remove packages when you don't need to.