# numpy Import Error on Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, numpy, importerror, sudoers

I am trying to import `numpy` in python on a server that I am **not** a sudoer. 
When I import, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv
```

I know that there are two conflicting libraries:

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/*.so.3gf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Sep 21 21:31 /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3gf -> /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Aug 19  2014 /etc/alternatives/liblapack.so.3gf -> /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3gf
```

But all the solutions that I have seen so far (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917977/installing-lapack-for-numpy) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249089/how-to-use-numpy-with-openblas-instead-of-atlas-in-ubuntu)), require root access, which I don't have. Is there a quick way to resolve this?

I am running python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get NumPy and other scientific libraries to work is to use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).

While Anaconda is a full distribution of libraries, Miniconda is just a improved Python installation. After downloading and installing Miniconda, which you can do without being a sudoer, create a new environment:

```
conda create -n my_new_env python=3.5
```

Activate it with

```
source activate my_new_env
```

and install NumPy

```
conda install numpy
```

Do all your Python work from a shell you tyoed `source activate my_new_env`, in.
The prompt should change to `(my_new_env)`.

All steps can be done as "normal" user; no `sudo` right necessary.

Comment: Thank you Mike! Yes it did then and now again! Great explanations! :)

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.