# Upgrading to R 2.15.2 can't load stats package

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04

Running Ubuntu 12.04. finally upgraded from 2.12 to 2.15.2 today and when I start R I get this error.

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

edit:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep "blas\|atlas"
ii  libatlas3gf-base                               3.8.4-3build1                                 Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, generic shared
ii  libblas-dev                                    1.2.20110419-2ubuntu1                         Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines 3, static library
ii  libblas3gf                                     1.2.20110419-2ubuntu1                         Basic Linear Algebra Reference implementations, shared library
ii  libopenblas-base                               0.1alpha2.2-3                                 Optimized BLAS (linear algebra) library based on GotoBLAS2
ii  libopenblas-dev                                0.1alpha2.2-3                                 Optimized BLAS (linear algebra) library based on GotoBLAS2
```

Anyone else have this problem or know how to fix?

Comment: added the deb http://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/ repository. then just sudo apt-get update. sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `dpkg -l | grep "blas\|atlas"`

Comment: http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/07/msg00640.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917977/installing-lapack-for-numpy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should uninstall `libopenblas-base`

See this for more: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=638236

---

On my box:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep "blas\|atlas"
ii  libatlas-dev                                   3.8.4-3build1                           Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, C header files
ii  libatlas3gf-base                               3.8.4-3build1                           Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, generic shared
ii  libblas-dev                                    1.2.20110419-2ubuntu1                   Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines 3, static library
ii  libblas3gf                                     1.2.20110419-2ubuntu1                   Basic Linear Algebra Reference implementations, shared library
ii  liblastfm0                                     0.4.0~really0.3.3-0ubuntu1              The Last.fm web services library
```

Comment: Is there a way for the CRAN/debian maintainers to manage this conflict in the package process?

Comment: Thanks. Is this a common issue?

Comment: @sayhey69, I don't know if it's common.  I ran into a similar problem when I had revolution-mkl installed, so I knew where to look..

Comment: Can we get more upvotes for this answer! If only i had seen this before would have saved me some sleepless nights!!