# ImportError with scipy/sklearn: `/usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, lapack

My code worked fine in Ubuntu 12.04, but now I have error:

```
  from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from .metrics import (accuracy_score,   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 25, in 
    from scipy.spatial.distance import hamming as sp_hamming   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 91, in 
    from .qhull import *  ImportError: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv
```

I don't understand what does this error mean and what should I do.

Comment: could you post your code here?

Comment: [Probably related to this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917977/installing-lapack-for-numpy)

Comment: Tried to do thing from than question (delete that package), but there is no reaction.

Answer (score 4):

can try this

```
sudo update-alternatives --set liblapack.so.3gf /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3gf
```

Comment: My comment is to state that this answer worked for me.

Comment: Hi, in my case I get this: `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for liblapack.so.3gf`. Any ideas? I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my guess at what happened:

1. The version of `scikit-learn` you installed back when you were running Ubuntu 12.04 was built against an older version of LAPACK, provided by `liblapack.so.3gf`.
2. When you (presumably) upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to whatever version you're using now, LAPACK was also upgraded to a newer version. In versions of Ubuntu >= 13.04, the LAPACK dependency for the `python-numpy` package is provided by `liblapack3`, `liblapack.so.3` or `libatlas3-base`, not `liblapack.so.3gf`.
3. Now `scikit-learn` tries to link against the newer version at runtime, but fails because of an incompatibility between the older and newer versions of LAPACK.

I would suggest you first try uninstalling and reinstalling `scikit-learn` using pip. Hopefully `scikit-learn` will then be rebuilt against the new LAPACK library, and everything should work fine from then on.

If that doesn't work, I would then try uninstalling any currently installed LAPACK libraries. This will probably force you to also uninstall `numpy` and `scipy`. I would then install `liblapack3`, as well as `libopenblas-base` and `libopenblas-dev` (which provide a faster alternative to the standard BLAS libraries), then reinstall `numpy`, `scipy` and `scikit-learn`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply installing `liblapack3` resolved the issue for me:

```
apt-get install liblapack3
```