# R on Linux, "package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found"

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have just installed R 3.1.1 on my Linux Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.
Then I wanted to install the [topicmodels](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/index.html) package, and so I type **install.packages("topicmodels")**, but the installation did not work.

It seems that I do not have the "stats" package installed in my default packages.
Here's the log:

```
> install.packages("topicmodels");
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
also installing the dependencies ‘modeltools’, ‘slam’, ‘tm’

provo con l'URL 'http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/src/contrib/modeltools_0.2-21.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 14794 bytes (14 Kb)
URL aperto
==================================================
downloaded 14 Kb

provo con l'URL 'http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/src/contrib/slam_0.1-32.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 46672 bytes (45 Kb)
URL aperto
==================================================
downloaded 45 Kb

provo con l'URL 'http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/src/contrib/tm_0.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 505212 bytes (493 Kb)
URL aperto
==================================================
downloaded 493 Kb

provo con l'URL 'http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/src/contrib/topicmodels_0.2-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 847889 bytes (828 Kb)
URL aperto
==================================================
downloaded 828 Kb

Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv
Durante l'avvio - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
* installing *source* package ‘modeltools’ ...
** package ‘modeltools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv
Error : package ‘stats’ could not be loaded
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘modeltools’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/modeltools’
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv
Durante l'avvio - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
* installing *source* package ‘slam’ ...
** package ‘slam’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c apply.c -o apply.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c grouped.c -o grouped.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c sparse.c -o sparse.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c util.c -o util.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o slam.so apply.o grouped.o sparse.o util.o -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/slam/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘slam’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/slam’
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv
Durante l'avvio - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
ERROR: dependency ‘slam’ is not available for package ‘tm’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/tm’
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv
Durante l'avvio - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
ERROR: dependencies ‘modeltools’, ‘slam’, ‘tm’ are not available for package ‘topicmodels’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/topicmodels’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpIppG4O/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("topicmodels") :
  installation of package ‘modeltools’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("topicmodels") :
  installation of package ‘slam’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("topicmodels") :
  installation of package ‘tm’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("topicmodels") :
  installation of package ‘topicmodels’ had non-zero exit status
```

Here's the output of the **dpkg -l | grep "blas\|atlas"** command:

```
ii  libatlas3gf-base   3.8.4-3build1  Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, generic shared
ii  libblas-dev        1.2.20110419-2ubuntu1  Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines 3, static library
ii  libblas3gf         1.2.20110419-2ubuntu1  Basic Linear Algebra Reference implementations, shared library
ii  libopenblas-base   0.1alpha2.2-3  Optimized BLAS (linear algebra) library based on GotoBLAS2
ii  libopenblas-dev    0.1alpha2.2-3  Optimized BLAS (linear algebra) library based on GotoBLAS2
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Generally one needs to address the first reported error. If R cannot find `stats`, then you need to figure out why.  You need to describe how your R was built. A fairly common route to fixing Linux issues is to go back and choose the "dev" versions rather than the "base" versions.

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks for showing interest. I installed R through the command `sudo apt-get install r-base`

Comment: As I suggested, it is fairly typical to run into problems if you did not install the dev version. That sets up R so that compiled packages have the correct headers for linkage. Suggest you install with `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`, instead. Then try to install your package.

Comment: @BondedDust I installed also 'r-base-dev' but nothing changed... any other idea? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917977/installing-lapack-for-numpy suggests looking for and removing incompatible lapack installs. (Sorry, my link-fu in comments is weak.)

Comment: @sjnarv I tried, but did not work... any other idea? Thanks

Comment: No, nothing specific. The log entry that caught my eye seems to say that stats.so *was* found on your system, and that it depends upon liblapack.so, but that library (the lapack one) fails to include the ATL_chemv symbol that your version of stats.so depends upon. My one google search for liblapack and ATL_chemv lead to the link I suggested. Perhaps you can find more if you explore more google results than I did...